# Sequelize: Calling .get({plain: true })) returns .get is not a function

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

I'm not sure why this would happen as Im returning only the values of an instance in other locations just fine.  See anything wrong with my code?

```
app.get('/profile', checkAuth, function(req, res) {
    var useObj = req.user;
    var guilds = req.user.guilds;
    User.findAll({
        where: { userid: useObj.id },
        include: [{
            model: Guild
        }]
    }).then(function(group) {
        console.log(group.get({
            plain: true
        }))
    })  
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to call `get` function of array, not instance, so, `findAll()` always returns an array of instances. Use `findOne()` instead or loop result